# Writing in file from shared buffer missing data and program crash without cout

Tags: c++, multithreading, file, crash

I am making a program using threads and a shared buffer. The two threads run indefinitely in the background, one thread will fill a shared buffer with data and the other thread will write the content of the shared buffer into a file.

The user can start or stop the data filling which is resulting in the thread entering into a waiting state until the user starts the thread again. Each loop the buffer is filled with 50 floats.

This is the code :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <fstream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::vector<std::vector<float>> datas;
bool keep_running = true, start_running = false;

void writing_thread()
{
    ofstream myfile;

    bool opn = false;

    while(1)
    {

        while(keep_running)
        {
            // Open the file only once
            if(!opn)
            {
                myfile.open("IQ_Datas.txt");
                opn = true;

            }


            // Wait until main() sends data
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);

            cv.wait(lk, [] {return !datas.empty();});


            auto d = std::move(datas);


            lk.unlock();


            for(auto &entry : d)
            {
                for(auto &e : entry)
                    myfile << e << endl;
            }


        }

        if(opn)
        {
            myfile.close();
            opn = false;
        }

    }
}

void sending_thread()
{

    std::vector<float> m_buffer;
    int cpt=0;
    //Fill the buffer with 50 floats
    for(float i=0; i<50; i++)
        m_buffer.push_back(i);

    while(1)
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
            cv.wait(lk, [] {return keep_running && start_running;});

        }
        while(keep_running)
        {

            //Each loop d is containing 50 floats
            std::vector<float> d = m_buffer;

            cout << "in3" << endl; //Commenting this line makes the program crash

            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
                if (!keep_running)break;
                datas.push_back(std::move(d));
            }
            cv.notify_one();
            cpt++;
        }

        cout << "Total data: " << cpt*50 << endl;
        cpt = 0;
    }
}
void start()
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        start_running = true;
    }
    cv.notify_all();
}
void stop()
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        start_running = false;
    }
    cv.notify_all();
}

int main()
{
    int go = 0;
    thread t1(sending_thread);
    thread t2(writing_thread);

    t1.detach();
    t2.detach();

    while(1)
    {

        std::cin >> go;

        if(go == 1)
        {
            start();
            keep_running = true;
        }
        else if(go == 0)
        {
            stop();
            keep_running = false;
        }


    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have 2 issues with this code :

- When commenting the line `cout << "in3" << endl;` the program will crash after ~20-40 seconds with the error message : **terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc**. If i let the cout, the program will run without problems.
- When the program is working, after stoping `sending_thread` i display the total amount of data that has been copied with `cout << "Total data: " << cpt*50 << endl;`. For small amount of datas, all of it is written correctly into the file but when the amount is big, there is missing data. [Missing/Correct data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYi7V.png) (Total number of lines in the file does not match `total data`)

Why with the cout the program is running correctly ? And what is causing the missing data ? Is it because `sending_thread` is filling the buffer too fast while `writing_thread`takes too much time to write into the file?

**EDIT:** Some precisions, adding more cout into `sending_thread`seems to fix all the issues. First thread produced 21 million floats and second thread successfully wrote in the file 21 million floats. It seems like without the cout, producer threads works too fast for the consumer thread to keep retrieving data from the shared buffer while writing it into a file.

Comment: It seems that your main thread alters the keep_running shared boolean variable without any sort of mutual exclusion. So the changes can remain "trapped" in the cache of the cpu core running the main thread. However, the fact of writing "in3" is a system call, which can force a cache flush, hence a possible explanation of the change in behavior. You should use proper mutual exclusion in the main thread too.

Comment: Alright, could i change the value of keep_running in the function `start`and `stop`to avoid this behavior ? Also, the fact that `keep_running` can remain trapped in the cache is causing the bad_alloc error?

Comment: Yes, moving the changes to a shared variable into a lock-protected region should help. Also, in your initial code, it is possible that the producer thread sees the change, and produces in non-stop fashion, while the consumer thread fails to see the change and stays put. Hence, a lot of data gets buffered, until resources are exhausted. But, generally speaking, it is not a very good use of people's time to speculate about why ill-synchronized programs happen to display such and such behavior.

Comment: @jpmarinier Running the program without changing the value of `keep_running` and `start_running` is still resulting in bad_alloc, maybe the issue is not from the shared variables. EDIT: after printing "1, 2 ... " in `writing_thread`it seems that the thread is stuck for a time in the for loops before calling bad_alloc

Comment: You need to reconsider this `auto d = std::move(datas);` which will leave your `datas` in unspecified state, maybe reconstructing `datas` after `move` giving it a new initial state will solve your missing data.

Comment: @muaz Yes i modified it as Ted Lyngmo adviced me. `auto d = std::move(datas);` is now `datas.swap(d);`. There is no missing data only when i put 3 cout (see my edit), really strange.

Comment: `cout` just slowing down your producer thread -which consumes your memory- giving a chance to the consumer thread to empty your vector, but more elegant solution will be giving a maximum size to your vector and not allowing the producer thread to push data until it gets empty again, then you do not need those `cout`

Comment: @muaz I guess an alternative could be `d.swap(datas)` instead of `datas.swap(d)` to clear and reallocate datas.

Comment: @muaz I added `if(datas.empty())datas.push_back(std::move(d));` to push data only when the vector is empty, it works but it's slow and i don't see how to give a maximum size for the vector because each loop `datas` is containing only one vector then its locked by consumer thread which copy from `datas` then empty it.

Comment: Just as a suggestion before `datas.push_back(std::move(d));` set this condition `if(datas.size() * d.size() * sizeof(float) < size )` where `size` is some integer represents a reasonable memory size in bytes allocated for `datas` say 2 MB.

Comment: `d.swap(datas)` instead of `datas.swap(d)` do the same thing. It's only a matter of who does the actual swapping (exchanging the pointers). Both are in a valid **and** specified state. Adding a check to only push if the vector is empty as a check if the client side has emptied the vector may cause race conditions. You would then have multiple checks for the same thing. Never a good sign. I'll look into it more closely when the Swedish midsummer is done :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I see, tried to put a cond var to wait for vector being empty but I didn't manage to make it work. I'll try again tomorrow, i'm tired haha :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid:

```
Moved-from object 'datas' of type 'std::vector' is moved:
        auto d = std::move(datas);
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Replace this:

```
        // Wait until main() sends data
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        cv.wait(lk, [] {return !datas.empty();});
        auto d = std::move(datas);
        lk.unlock();
```

With this:

```
        // Wait until main() sends data            
        std::vector<std::vector<float>> d;
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
            cv.wait(lk, [] { return !datas.empty(); });
            datas.swap(d);
        }
```

Also replace your `bool` variables that are accessed from multiple threads with `std::atomic_bool` or `std::atomic_flag`.

The `bad_alloc` comes from `sending_thread` being much faster than `writing_thread` so it will run out of memory. When you slow down `sending_thread` enough (with printing), the problem is less visible, but you should have some synchronization to do it properly. You could make a wrapper class around it and provide insert and extraction methods to make sure all access is synchronized properly and also give it a max number of elements. An example:

```
template<typename T>
class atomic2dvector {
public:
    atomic2dvector(size_t max_elements) : m_max_elements(max_elements) {}

    atomic2dvector(const atomic2dvector&) = delete;
    atomic2dvector(atomic2dvector&&) = delete;
    atomic2dvector& operator=(const atomic2dvector&) = delete;
    atomic2dvector& operator=(atomic2dvector&&) = delete;

    ~atomic2dvector() { shutdown(); }

    bool insert_one(std::vector<T>&& other) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mtx);
        while(m_current_elements + m_data.size() > m_max_elements && m_shutdown == false)
            m_cv.wait(lock);
        if(m_shutdown) return false;

        m_current_elements += other.size();
        m_data.emplace_back(std::forward<std::vector<T>>(other));

        m_cv.notify_one();
        return true;
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> extract_all() {
        std::vector<std::vector<T>> return_value;

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mtx);
        while(m_data.empty() && m_shutdown == false) m_cv.wait(lock);

        if(m_shutdown == false) {
            m_current_elements = 0;
            return_value.swap(m_data);
        } else {
            // return an empty vector if we should shutdown
        }
        m_cv.notify_one();

        return return_value;
    }

    bool is_active() const { return m_shutdown == false; }

    void shutdown() {
        m_shutdown = true;
        m_cv.notify_all();
    }

private:
    size_t m_max_elements;
    size_t m_current_elements = 0;
    std::atomic<bool> m_shutdown = false;
    std::condition_variable m_cv{};
    std::mutex m_mtx{};
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> m_data{};
};
```

If you'd like to keep extracting data even after shutdown, you can change `extract_all()` to this:

```
   std::vector<std::vector<T>> extract_all() {
        std::vector<std::vector<T>> return_value;

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mtx);
        while(m_data.empty() && m_shutdown == false) m_cv.wait(lock);

        m_current_elements = 0;
        return_value.swap(m_data);
        m_cv.notify_one();

        return return_value;
    }
```

A full example could look like this:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class atomic2dvector {
public:
    atomic2dvector(size_t max_elements) : m_max_elements(max_elements) {}
    atomic2dvector(const atomic2dvector&) = delete;
    atomic2dvector(atomic2dvector&&) = delete;
    atomic2dvector& operator=(const atomic2dvector&) = delete;
    atomic2dvector& operator=(atomic2dvector&&) = delete;

    ~atomic2dvector() { shutdown(); }

    bool insert_one(std::vector<T>&& other) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mtx);
        while(m_current_elements + m_data.size() > m_max_elements &&
              m_shutdown == false)
            m_cv.wait(lock);
        if(m_shutdown) return false;

        m_current_elements += other.size();
        m_data.emplace_back(std::forward<std::vector<T>>(other));

        m_cv.notify_one();
        return true;
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> extract_all() {
        std::vector<std::vector<T>> return_value;

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mtx);
        while(m_data.empty() && m_shutdown == false) m_cv.wait(lock);

        m_current_elements = 0;
        return_value.swap(m_data);
        m_cv.notify_one();

        return return_value;
    }

    bool is_active() const { return m_shutdown == false; }

    void shutdown() {
        m_shutdown = true;
        m_cv.notify_all();
    }

private:
    size_t m_max_elements;
    size_t m_current_elements = 0;
    std::atomic<bool> m_shutdown = false;
    std::condition_variable m_cv{};
    std::mutex m_mtx{};
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> m_data{};
};

std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
atomic2dvector<float> datas(256 * 1024 * 1024 / sizeof(float)); // 0.25 GiB limit
std::atomic_bool start_running = false;

void writing_thread() {
    std::ofstream myfile("IQ_Datas.txt");
    if(myfile) {
        std::cout << "writing_thread waiting\n";

        std::vector<std::vector<float>> d;
        while((d = datas.extract_all()).empty() == false) {
            std::cout << "got " << d.size() << "\n";

            for(auto& entry : d) {
                for(auto& e : entry) myfile << e << "\n";
            }
            std::cout << "wrote " << d.size() << "\n\n";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "writing_thread shutting down\n";
}

void sending_thread() {
    std::vector<float> m_buffer;
    std::uintmax_t cpt = 0;
    // Fill the buffer with 50 floats
    for(float i = 0; i < 50; i++) m_buffer.push_back(i);

    while(true) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
            cv.wait(lk, [] {
                return start_running == true || datas.is_active() == false;
            });
        }
        if(datas.is_active() == false) break;
        std::cout << "sending...\n";
        while(start_running == true) {
            // Each loop d is containing 50 floats
            std::vector<float> d = m_buffer;
            if(datas.insert_one(std::move(d)) == false) break;
            cpt++;
        }
        cout << "Total data: " << cpt * 50 << endl;
        cpt = 0;
    }
    std::cout << "sending_thread shutting down\n";
}

void start() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    start_running = true;
    cv.notify_all();
}
void stop() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    start_running = false;
    cv.notify_all();
}
void quit() {
    datas.shutdown();
    cv.notify_all();
}

int main() {
    int go = 0;
    thread t1(sending_thread);
    thread t2(writing_thread);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    std::cout << "Enter 1 to make the sending thread send and 0 to make it stop "
                 "sending. Enter a non-integer to shutdown.\n";

    while(std::cin >> go) {
        if(go == 1) {
            start();
        } else if(go == 0) {
            stop();
        }
    }
    std::cout << "--- shutting down ---\n";
    quit();

    std::cout << "joining threads\n";
    t1.join();
    std::cout << "t1 joined\n";
    t2.join();
    std::cout << "t2 joined\n";
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195483/discussion-on-answer-by-ted-lyngmo-writing-in-file-from-shared-buffer-missing-da).